# UICollectionViewCell position gets doubled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I just noticed that the center of uicollectionviewcells is half of the real center.

example:

setting frames for cells to:

```
[0] {{0, 0}, {100, 100}}
[1] {{100, 100}, {100, 100}}
[2] {{200, 200}, {100, 100}}
[3] {{300, 300}, {100, 100}}
[4] {{400, 400}, {100, 100}}
[5] {{500, 500}, {100, 100}}
```

note: this are the values i get from setFrame, and [applyLayoutAttributes:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/applyLayoutAttributes:)

looks like this:
[image: actual look]

but should look like this:
[image: how it should look]

### implementation of UICollectionViewLayout subclass

```
@implementation CVTLayout

- (void)prepareLayout {
    [super prepareLayout];

    CollectionViewTable *cvt = (CollectionViewTable*)self.collectionView;


    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(50, 50);
    NSMutableArray *cellAttributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int item = 0; item < [cvt.cellValues count]; item++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:0];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
        attributes.size = size;
        attributes.center = center;
        [cellAttributes addObject:attributes];

        center.x += size.width;
        center.y += size.height;
    }
    cvt.cellAttributes = cellAttributes;
}

- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
    return self.collectionView.bounds.size;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewTable *cvt = (CollectionViewTable*)self.collectionView;
    return cvt.cellAttributes[indexPath.item];
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSMutableArray *layoutAttributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CollectionViewTable *cvt = (CollectionViewTable*)self.collectionView;
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *cellAttributes in cvt.cellAttributes) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, cellAttributes.frame)) {
            [layoutAttributes addObject:cellAttributes];
        }
    }
    return layoutAttributes;
}

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return false;
}

@end
```

---

Comment: What is the position of the red overlay?

Comment: the applied position for the cell with the green overlay

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here.

Comment: @ipmcc tried to clarify my question

Comment: Is there a non-identity transform applied to the view? It'd be useful to see some sample code.

Comment: @AndrewHershberger nope there is no non-identity transform

Comment: added code of collectionviewlayout-subclass, and removed the first example so first 2 comments can be ignored

Comment: @peko The layout code looks okay. I'd next be interested to see a dump of the view hierarchy. Try running in the debugger, pausing execution, then run `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` at the debugger prompt.

Comment: @peko you might also try setting breakpoints on `-[UIView setFrame:]`, `-[UIView setBounds:]`, `-[UIView setCenter:]`: `breakpoint set -F '-[UIView setCenter:]'` then look at the stack to see where they're getting set. I'd reduce the number of items to 2 if you do this though.

Comment: I don't get what your doing here -- it looks like you're getting your cell attributes from the collection view, rather than providing them from this class. In layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: you just return cvt.cellAttributes[indexPath.item], but I don't even see where that method ever gets called (usually it's called from layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: in the examples I've seen). What do you have in cvt.cellAttributes?

Comment: cvt.cellAttributes is an array with UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes and i'm reading the Cell-Frame in setFrame and applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was setting the cell-label-frame to the cell-frame instead of the cell-bounds...